# Couchdb - data in docker volume not accessible (copy from other cdb instance)

Tags: docker, couchdb

I'm trying to copy whole data folder from one instance of CouchDB (single node) into Docker volume and I have issues accessing those databases getting error(s) below

```
[notice] 2018-12-02T09:46:18.664647Z nonode@nohost <0.313.0> -------- chttpd_auth_cache changes listener died database_does_not_exist at mem3_shards:load_shards_from_db/6(line:395) <= mem3_shards:load_shards_from_disk/1(line:370) <= mem3_shards:load_shards_from_disk/2(line:399) <= mem3_shards:for_docid/3(line:86) <= fabric_doc_open:go/3(line:38) <= chttpd_auth_cache:ensure_auth_ddoc_exists/2(line:187) <= chttpd_auth_cache:listen_for_changes/1(line:134)
[error] 2018-12-02T09:46:18.664764Z nonode@nohost emulator -------- Error in process <0.12460.0> with exit value: {database_does_not_exist,[{mem3_shards,load_shards_from_db,"_users",[{file,"src/mem3_shards.erl"},{line,395}]},{mem3_shards,load_shards_from_disk,1,[{file,"src/mem3_shards.erl"},{line,370}]},{mem3_shards,load_shards_from_disk,2,[{file,"src/mem3_shards.erl"},{line,399}]},{mem3_shards,for_docid,3,[{file,"src/mem3_shards.erl"},{line,86}]},{fabric_doc_open,go,3,[{file,"src/fabric_doc_open.erl"},{line,38}]},{chttpd_auth_cache,ensure_auth_ddoc_exists,2,[{file,"src/chttpd_auth_cache.erl"},{line,187}]},{chttpd_auth_cache,listen_for_changes,1,[{file,"src/chttpd_auth_cache.erl"},{line,134}]}]}
[error] 2018-12-02T09:51:20.301152Z nonode@nohost <0.17260.0> 45e2192077 req_err(2686395495) internal_server_error : No DB shards could be opened.[<<"fabric_util:get_shard/4 L185">>,<<"fabric:get_security/2 L146">>,<<"chttpd_auth_request:db_authorization_check/1 L98">>,<<"chttpd_auth_request:authorize_request/1 L19">>,<<"chttpd:handle_req_after_auth/2 L315">>,<<"chttpd:process_request/1 L300">>,<<"chttpd:handle_request_int/1 L240">>,<<"mochiweb_http:headers/6 L124">>]
[notice] 2018-12-02T09:51:20.301604Z nonode@nohost <0.17260.0> 45e2192077 127.0.0.1:5984 172.17.0.1 adminis GET /mydatabase 500 ok 4
[error] 2018-12-02T09:51:20.301455Z nonode@nohost <0.17258.0> fe8bc3ea8a req_err(2686395495) internal_server_error : No DB shards could be opened. [<<"fabric_util:get_shard/4 L185">>,<<"fabric:get_security/2 L146">>,<<"chttpd_auth_request:db_authorization_check/1 L98">>,<<"chttpd_auth_request:authorize_request/1 L19">>,<<"chttpd:handle_req_after_auth/2 L315">>,<<"chttpd:process_request/1 L300">>,<<"chttpd:handle_request_int/1 L240">>,<<"mochiweb_http:headers/6 L124">>]
[notice] 2018-12-02T09:51:20.303896Z nonode@nohost <0.17258.0> fe8bc3ea8a 127.0.0.1:5984 172.17.0.1 admin GET /mydatabase-v2 500 ok 6
```

I'm able to access these data in non-docker couchdb instance so it has to be something within docker that prevents me to properly access the data. Running couchdb v2.2.0 in all instancies, SElinux context and ACL are correct. Only difference I see between docker and non-docker instance is the host definition (eg. docker has nonode@nohost while local instance has couchdb@127.0.0.1).

Any idea what might be wrong?

Comment: Can you add more info, shell script, dockerfile, etc?

Comment: we had the same problem so we switched to a single instance that took a snapshot during termination. We've done a lot of testing and it appears that even though the db(s) are not corrupted the new instance can never read the old data. I think there is something in the instance that is required to read data from the db. we initially thought it was a combination of vm.args & uuid but have not found the magic bullet. Good luck

Comment: @bflemi3 sorry for delay (SO notifications end up in my spam folder :-O). There is no special shell script or docker file, I simply pull couchdb and create persistent volume for data attached to the couchdb docker instance, then simply copy the data either through sftp or directly on the host (to the persistent volume location). I solved the problem simply by replicating the data from the host but my curiosity why I can't just simply copy the data is not yet satisfied :)